# OptionalProps in Mikro-orm

Tags: node.js, typescript, mikro-orm

I am trying to work out how to define additional optional properties.

```
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property, OptionalProps } from '@mikro-orm/core';

@Entity()
export abstract class BaseEntity {
  [OptionalProps]?: 'createdAt';

  @PrimaryKey()
  id: number;

  @Property()
  createdAt: Date = new Date();

}

@Entity()
export class EntityA extends BaseEntity {
  [OptionalProps]?: 'isAnotherProperty'; // This is the bit I cannot figure out

  @Property()
  isAnotherProperty: boolean = false;

}
```

With the above TypeScript throws an error:

```
Property '[OptionalProps]' in type 'EntityA' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseEntity'.
```

Basically my `BaseEntity` has optional properties, as does `EntityA`. I could remove `[OptionalProps]?:` from `BaseEntity` and have `[OptionalProps]?: 'createdAt' | 'isAnotherProperty';` in `EntityA`, but many of my entities don't require any additional optional properties beyond `createdAt` so I prefer not to have to duplicate `[OptionalProps]?: 'createdAt';` in every entity class if I could just 'extend' it where I need to.

Is it at all possible to either append to or override `[OptionalProps]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 2023 update

The upcoming v6 will have another way to mark optional properties on type-level - the `Opt` type, which does not suffer from the extension issues. You can use in two ways (and it won't :

```
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property, Opt } from '@mikro-orm/core';

@Entity()
export abstract class BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryKey()
  id: number;

  @Property()
  createdAt: Date & Opt = new Date(); // either intersect

}

@Entity()
export class EntityA extends BaseEntity<'isAnotherProperty'> {

  @Property()
  isAnotherProperty: Opt<boolean> = false; // or use it as a generic

}
```

This approach can be combined with the `OptionalProps` symbol.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/next/guide/relationships#alternative-approach-with-opt-type

---

### Older (but still valid) approach

Probably the cleanest approach is via type argument on the base entity:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property, OptionalProps } from '@mikro-orm/core';

@Entity()
export abstract class BaseEntity<Optional = never> {

  [OptionalProps]?: Optional | 'createdAt';

  @PrimaryKey()
  id: number;

  @Property()
  createdAt: Date = new Date();

}

@Entity()
export class EntityA extends BaseEntity<'isAnotherProperty'> {

  @Property()
  isAnotherProperty: boolean = false;

}
```

Comment: I tried both, the first option worked, but with the second option I get `'Omit' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`. I have opted for the first as that seems to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: You forgot to use `typeof` there, the second approach works also just fine. You can ses it being used in the tests: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/tests/entities-schema/Test4.ts

edit: or maybe it does not work with classes but just interfaces, not sure now. I would still stuggest the first approach as its much cleaner.

Comment: @MartinAdámek I assume there were two options in the answer, but now it's only one, right? And how to properly make the `O` generic type optional? Will it be `export abstract class BaseEntity<O = never>`?

Comment: Yeah my initial idea wasn't working :] `never` should do the job, as it gets removed from union types, e.g. `number | string | never` simplifies to `number | string`.